# UITableView not loading data from API call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my code I have a search bar that when its search button is clicked, it triggers this function here:

```
func getStocks(ticker: String) {
        do {
            try Stocks.getStocks(ticker, completion: {stockList in
                self.listOfStocks = stockList
                print("Stock item is: \n", self.listOfStocks.popLast())
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.saveStocks(self.listOfStocks.popLast()!)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })
            } catch {
                print("Failed to get stocks")
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this function is to go through my API call, get data for the item the user has specified in the search bar, append it to a global list of items while also saving the most recent item in the global list into Core Data. Later on I have a block of code that sets the text cell label and sets it to the name property of my Stock struct:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stockItem", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let label:UILabel = cell.textLabel {
        label.text = self.listOfStocks[indexPath.row].name
    }

    return cell
}
```

I've checked to make sure the reuse identifier is correct so that wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Have you checked that the data is populating your datasource, listOfStocks?

Comment: Nothing is jumping out to me...seeeeems ok. Can you confirm that it is at least reloading the cells (calling cellForRowAtIndexPath) after you call tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: @fragilecat I've just done a check by printing listOfStocks outside of the do statement and I get "[]" back so the list is empty

Comment: Then the issue is with your api call, start tracing it :)

Comment: @fragilecat In my API call I add the data gathered and put it into a Stock struct, I then print the result of the Stock struct and all of the data in there is correct so the API call is working properly

Comment: print("Stock item is: \( self.listOfStocks.popLast()))

Comment: Excuse me, change your print line to the print statement above.

Comment: Then check your listOfStocks for data in the tableview method.

Comment: I've checked in the tableView method but it doesn't seem to print, which makes me think that for some reason the tableView method isn't running.

Comment: Does it print anything at all?

Comment: Nothing is printed whatsoever, nothing gets printed inside libdispatch either

Comment: Ok replace the label text  with: cell.textLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)" and confirm that the table populates this. That will confirm your table view logic is working.

Comment: I added `        if let label:UILabel = cell.textLabel {
            label.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        }`  and nothing is being printed in the table view

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to track down where in your code is the issue. I would follow these steps to do that.

1. Confirm that your Stocks.getStocks() static function is working correctly and that the api call is returning valid data. You have not supplied code for this.
2. Check that your data source, in this case `self.listOfStocks`  is being populated with the data from the API call. Set a breakpoint or use a print statement in the getStocks() method.

`

```
func getStocks(ticker: String) {
        do {
            try Stocks.getStocks(ticker, completion: {stockList in

                if let list = stockList {
                    self.listOfStocks = list
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let last = self.listOfStocks.popLast() {
                            self.saveStocks(last)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })

                } else {
                    print("ERROR: stockList is nil!")
                }
            })
            } catch {
                print("Failed to get stocks")
        }
   }
```

3. Review your table view delegate and dataSource delegate methods are correctly setup. Below is how I would check my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stockItem", forIndexPath: indexPath)

   ```
   if let datasource = self.listOfStocks[indexPath.row] {
       textLabel.text = datSource.name
   } else {
       textLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row): NOT set!"
   }

   return cell
   ```

   }